# Possible to save OpenXML Spreadsheet without calling Close()?

Tags: c#, .net, spreadsheet, openxml

I'm writing a spreadsheet utility using OpenXML, and need to be able to periodically (or even on every cell update) *save* the document.  After this save, the document must be in a valid (readable) state.

The only examples I've seen leave the document in a corrupted state until

```
document.Close();
```

is called.  Even though there are periodic calls to

```
worksheet.Save();
```

the document will be corrupted until `Close()` is called.

I need to quickly be able to save the document on the fly, as the document will be open for a long period of time, written to frequently, and if the program crashes, I need to be able to access any data that was written while the program was running (and obviously I can't rely on Close() being called).

I don't necessarily need to implement this with low-level OpenXML, but all the wrappers I've tried (ClosedXml, NPOI) seem to have this same shortcoming.

Comment: Please share with us how you open the file.

Comment: In general, the file can already exist and be opened by .Open(), but in most cases this utility will create a spreadsheet based on a specified file name, using . Create().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the document using [the following](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc562185).

```
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docName, true))
{
}
```

When you specify `true` the stream is marked as editable, and can accept edits on the fly.

Make sure you read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff478410) article, that will give you some examples on how to fool around with open XML streams.